# "A destination table has not been provided" when using variable for OLE DB Name SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am setting up a For Each File Loop to upload all the text files in a folder and create a DB item with the same name. This however is causing me to get the above error. As you can see from the two screenshots below, I have (I think) set the Connection Manager for the OLE DB Destination object up correctly, but the error remains. Does anyone know why I am getting this and where I am supposed to specify a table name if a declared variable is being used for the looping?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your variable definition (User::FileFound), you have to specify the sheet name in the Excel workbook you used to set up your Excel Connection Manager (e.g. 'Sheet1$').

You're presumably changing the value of the variable at some point in your For Each File loop process, which makes sense, but at design time, you have to specify a real sheet name.

Answer (score 0):

In your Control Flow, click on your data Flow Component

On properties, change the 'DelayValidation' to 'True'

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. I have already done this and am still getting the error. any ideas?

Comment: Use a breakpoint to check if your variable isn't empty and if the field contains a value, check the format.